# Disk space utilization in GB on Linux

Tags: linux, disk

I want to calculate the temporary amount of disk space used by an application in GB on Linux(ubuntu 14.04)
How can I do it?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/490945/how-much-space-does-a-given-package-and-dependencies-cost

Comment: Can you please clarify "The temporary amount of disk space used by an application"?

Comment: BTW Ubuntu 14.04 is quite old. You should upgrade your Linux distribution

Answer (score 2):

> I want to calculate the temporary amount of disk space used by an application in GB

In general you cannot do that. However, you might use [du(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html), [df(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html) (perhaps using [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) from inside your application).

BTW, you don't define what is the *temporary amount of disk space*. Is it related to [tmpfile(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html) or [mkstemp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html)? Or [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) with `O_TMPFILE`?

<sup>(actually, defining *precisely* what is the temporary amount of disk space is **not easy** at all; once you did that you could get a better answer)</sup>

Maybe you want to measure the size of temporary files in some [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) running your application (that is, those files which have an open [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), but whose name was `unlink`-ed from their directory). Then read much more about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). From *inside* your application, consider using `/proc/self/fd/` (you could [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), `closedir` it etc). From *outside* your application, if its process is 1234, consider using `/proc/1234/fd/`